# iOS Subscription Verification

Tags: ios, storekit

I have an interesting problem... (for me at least)

I have developed an app that uses an auto-renewing subscription. They way I have it set up, the app saves the subscription receipt then each time the subscription needs to be verified, the app sends the receipt info to my server, which verifies the receipt is still valid.

In my app I have an app-wide constant called "testMode". Among other things, this causes the app to query my server with either a Sandbox, or Production flag. So if I am testing the app in test mode, the app will query a file on my server that checks the sandbox Apple server. If the app is not in test mode (like when I submit it to Apple) it queries the production file on my server which checks the data against Apple's production server.

My app was rejected because it produced an error when subscribing. That error was 21007 which means a sandbox receipt was sent to the production verification server.

So my question is: How can I submit an app that users the production server verification, if the Apple testers use the sandbox environment?

Comment: Can you provide Apple with a 'dummy' account info in the review notes when you submit your app?

Comment: The app doesn't use accounts

Answer (score 0):

I ran into similar issues. This is the best way to handle it:

Whenever your server receives a new receipt from the app, first verify it with the production server.  Then if you get error 21007, try the same receipt with the sandbox server.  This is what I do and it has worked well.  Apple should recommend this, but they don't.

Using this method, you should be able to get rid of your testMode in the app (unless you use it for other purposes).